# Was Dr. Octavius Brine inspired by Octodad?

Tags: inspiration, penguins-of-madagascar, octodad

In the 2014 science fiction action comedy animated film *Penguins of Madagascar*, the villain Dr. Octavius Brine is a genetic scientist who is actually an octopus, but masquarades as a human.  The protagonist of the 2010 video game *Octodad* (and its 2014 sequel) is also an octopus masquarading as a human.  They even move somewhat similarly.  Did the video game inspire the creators of the film when they made this character?

I would prefer an answer based on what any of the staff of the film said, such as in an interview, over speculation.

---

*This question has been closed as off topic and reopened again, twice, as can be seen in its [timeline](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/104077/timeline).*

*The question about its topicality has been put to a [vote on meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9642/19561), and the outcome seems to point to **the movie*** Penguins of Madagascar *being **on topic***

Comment: Discussions on On-Topicness: [Animation questions](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3167/are-questions-from-sci-fi-animation-movies-off-topic), [Spy questions](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/337/are-works-that-arent-sf-per-se-but-have-occasional-sfnal-elements-on-topic-e)

Comment: I'm voting to reopen, **but** only so it can be migrated to Movies & TV.

Comment: According to Meta, [this is on-topic](https://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9642/is-penguins-of-madagascar-on-topic). The close-reopen cycle is now over.

Comment: @anaranjada - I don't, it's true. I was just stating what seemed to be the consensus of the community. I asked Rand how long to wait before declaring consensus, and he said about 24 hours was good. The more popular view was pretty clear from the beginning, in any case.

Comment: @anaranjada - I think it was Rand. He said Meta had only a few regular users, and that I should just try to get all time zones.

Comment: @Jonah You must be getting me mixed up with someone else, and possibly a different site. SFF meta has quite a bunch of regular users/voters, but 24 hours often isn't enough to get a very clear consensus, especially at the weekend.

Comment: @Rand - Probably! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [this article](http://www.collider.com/penguins-of-madagascar-comic-con-panel-recap/);

> John Malkovich ... said he was presented with the offer [to play Dr. Brine] 3 ½ years ago.

<sup><sup>Collider reporting on the 2014 Comic-Con DreamWorks panel</sup></sup>

That article was written in July, 2014. If we say that John Malkovich was offered the part at the start of 2011 (which is roughly 3 ½ years ago) , then we can see that it is very unlikely for *Octodad!* to have influenced the development of *Penguins of Madagasar*, as *Octodad!* was developed for the 2011 Independent Games Festival, and did not get much attention until the sequel *Octodad: Dadliest Catch* was released in 2014.

Comment: In that case, could he have been inspired by Octomom?